# Setup proxmox internal network

Tags: networking, lan, proxmox

I am in need of a internal network on my Proxmox 3.4 installation.
I want to use a proxy server to route all my servers to the internet and back. That way I only have the need for one WAN address.

I only use containers and have one vm available. 
I've created a vmbr1 nic (10.0.0.1, 255.0.0.0), and a container with vmbr1 as eht0, assigned a static ip to it (10.0.0.102, 255.0.0.0) which contains a DHCP server to lease ips between 10.0.0.10 and 10.0.0.100.

When I connect a new container with vmbr1 as eth0 I do not get a ip address leased to it. DHCP service is running.

What am I doing wrong, or what did I forget? Any help would be gladly appreciated. Kind regards, Roberto

Comment: Can you first check if the container can connect through a static IP to the VM? Just give it any IP, and set its default GW to 10.0.0.102.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello recommend running 2 nic eth0 and eth1 
eth0 public 
eth1 private manual ip config  , like 192.168.1.xxx
use public to login to proxmox console from world wide and private to developer environment